# What is the etiquette for declining money from a Japanese friend?

Tags: japan, etiquette, cultural-awareness

My son's best friend is here from Japan. His parents paid for his plane ticket and sent $1,000 cash. We would like to return the money to them - his stay and expenses are our treat.

How can we do this without offending them?

Comment: We are in the US.  Money was sent on the plane with him.

Comment: There is a proposal for a Stack Exchange site on just this topic alone, [Etiquette](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53721/etiquette). I advise you to follow it, recommend it to friends and contribute to it when it makes it to beta. It will be a much better place to ask questions of this nature than Travel Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 15):

The best thing would be to simply make sure that the kid does not need to spend money while there. If the kid comes back to his parents and states "I only spent 100 for a souvenir", this would be much better than you sending then the money in any other way.

Possibly find a compromise that the kid can spend some things by himself, like inviting you all for dinner once or other symbolic things.

Comment: That last one is an excellent idea. It's sort of a way for him to give something back to his hosts. Sort of.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  They are a wonderful family, and we just do not want to do anything to offend them.  We are paying for everything, but perhaps will let their son purchase a souvenir on his own.  That might be a good compromise.  Again, thank you.

Comment: @Kim if this answer solved your question, then consider clicking the tick next to this answer.